# Problems by import of a multiple modules maven 2 project into eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, integration, m2eclipse, generated-code

I was wondering if someone has experienced the same problem as me and can help me. 
I have a maven project which contains 6 modules. Some of modules are depending on each other. The project is written in Java and builds to jars, wars and aar. I've been trying to import it to Eclipse with the m2eclipse plug-in. It seems to work fine until the project builds. During the build process I get hundreds of errors complaining about missing Java files which are generated. As I found out eclipse can't recognize that some of generated packages should be interpreted as source code. I don't realy know what to do with it as I spent a lot of time already trying to solve this issue. The project is building fine with command line. My target is to debug the whole project on Tomcat server that's why I want to use eclipse as it has a pretty good integration with Tomcat.

Every help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As documented in the [Why generated source folders are not added to classpath](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Project+FAQ#ProjectFAQ-generated) entry of the FAQ:

> Maven plugins used to generate source
>   code from resources or other sources
>   can register additional source folders
>   to Maven project during the build.
>   Usually such plugins are bound to
>   process-resources (or
>   process-test-resources) build phase
>   (for example jaxb, modello or xdoclet
>   plugins). This means that to get those
>   source folders for generated sources,
>   we have to run corresponding Maven
>   build phase.
>
> Not all projects using generated
>   sources, so for performance reasons,
>   m2eclipse does not run any Maven goals
>   by default on project import. This can
>   be changed in the Maven settings in
>   "**Window** > **Preferences...** > **Maven** >
>   **Goals to run on project import**" (e.g.
>   you can specify "process-resources"
>   build phase or specific plugins in
>   that field).
>
> Alternatively you can run "**Maven** >
>   **Update project configuration**" action
>   from the project popup menu, which is
>   configured to run "process-resources"
>   by default and it can be also changed
>   on the same preference page.

So either add the goal to which the source generation process is bound to the list of goals to run on import or generate sources by running maven and update the project configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much Pascal. Sorry, I didn't check it before.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

Under the project where you have additionally generated source. When this is generated by maven it is normally under target folder.

Therefor `eclipse:eclipse` will recognize this and add as a source folder.

Rembember to refresh the  project after this.

Answer (score 0):

Use **build-helper-maven-plugin** (sample bellow) to tell Eclipse to add a generated folder to the build path :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>target/generated-sources/cxf</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Add this in the pom of each project that generates sources...