# How can I generate-sources on project import/update with m2e

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I used to add "generate-resources" to Maven's "Goals to run on project import" setting in older m2e.

Now I have new version of eclispe and m2e, and the setting is gone.

How can I add the generated-sources o the eclipse project automatically?

see this older question:

[Problems by import of a multiple modules maven 2 project into eclipse workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421631/problems-by-import-of-a-multiple-modules-maven-2-project-into-eclipse-workspace)

I am using m2e 1.0.200.20111228-1245,

Eclipse version is as follows
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

Maven is: 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)

Pls. note that this is a centrally managed system, I have no root access etc.

Comment: You know that during the import the lifecycle is running which includes generate-resources...It depends which version of m2e/m2eclipse Eclise version you are using.

Comment: @khmarbaise I would expect that, but I also expected that eclipse picks up the generated-souirces in target as src folder.